# Given two audio files, one of which is a snippet of the other, is there a python way to find when the snippet is replayed in the original file?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, time, split

I have recorded some music and uploaded to instagram, which imposed a minute-long duration per clip. I've lost the original files and have these minute-long clips compiled such that `song__AA0, song__AA1, song__AA2, ...` correspond to a single song named `AA`, and repeated for `BB, CC, ...`. But because I clipped the videos manually, the beginning of `song__AA1` will repeat the segment that `song__AA0` ends; similarly, the beginning of `song__A2` will repeat the segment that song `song__AA1` ends. I've tried concatenating these minute-long clips, but finding the exact times at which to trim files is difficult manually. Is there a method in python that can be used to find the times at which the beginning of the `i+1`-th song and the end of the `i`-th song overlap such that I can concatenate these files accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to go with audio fingerprinting, with e.g. [Dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu). *An acoustic fingerprint is a condensed digital summary, a fingerprint, deterministically generated from an audio signal, that can be used to identify an audio sample or quickly locate similar items in an audio database.*.

Essentially, `dejavu` will create hashes over [spectrograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) of the audio.

First, create or connect to MySQL where Dejavu will store fingerprints.

```
from dejavu import Dejavu
config = {
    "database": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "user": "root",
        "passwd": <password above>, 
        "db": <name of the database you created above>,
    }
}
djv = Dejavu(config)
num_processes = 8
audio_extension = [".mp3", ".wav"]
djv.fingerprint_directory("directory_with_long_songs", audio_extension, num_processes)
```

Now that you have created fingerprints, you can do the recognition

```
from dejavu.recognize import FileRecognizer
song = djv.recognize(FileRecognizer, "your_shorter.wav")
```

Consult the docs for API and interpretation of the output.

`Dejavu` is one of many such programs. You can create your own fingerprinting algorithm by following e.g. [Shazam paper](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf).